# Specific Custom Design Layout for Product Attribute Set

Tags: layout, products, attribute-set

My store has 2 different types of `Attribute Sets` for my `Simple Products`:

```
Default
Custom
```

For all my products that have the attribute set name of `Custom` I need to remove the following sections from the page layout:

```
<reference name="root">
    <remove name="header" />
    <remove name="breadcrumbs" />
    <remove name="footer" />
</reference>
```

Is there a way i can easily assign all products in this attribute set to always remove these 3 sections.

I know I can place the above in the `Custom Design Layout` section but I currently have over 100,000 products with the attribute set of Custom so going through one by one is not an option.

Comment: you want to change attribute set or what?

Comment: No, the attribute set stays as it is but all products with the attribute set of `Custom` i want to remove the `header` `footer` and `breadcrumbs`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this case, we can add new  layout handler on basic of `Attribute Sets` at event `controller_action_layout_load_before`.

**Event:** `controller_action_layout_load_before`

**Condition:**  product attribute set

So , i am start an observer on basic of this condition which is add new
handler on current layout
.

**Handler Format:**  `PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_SET_{ProdductAttributSetName}`

**Observer code:**

```
<?php
class [ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Model_Observe{ 
/**
     * Before load layout event handler
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */
    public function beforeLoadLayout($observer)
    {
        if($observer->getEvent()->getAction()->getFullActionName()=='catalog_product_view'){
        $product = Mage::registry('current_product');
        if($product):
        $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
        $attributeSet = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')->load($product->getAttributeSetId());
        $handle = str_replace('-', '_', $product->formatUrlKey($attributeSet->getAttributeSetName()));

        $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_SET_'.$handle);
        // check all Handler 
        //Zend_Debug::dump($layout->getUpdate()->getHandles());
        endif;
        }
    return ;
    }


}
```

**Config.xml code;**

```
<global>
    <models>
        <[MyCustomModule_Model_Class_Groupname]>
            <class>[ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Model</class>
        </[MyCustomModule_Model_Class_Groupname]>
    </models>
</global>
   <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_layout_load_before>
                <observers>
                    <my_current_page_is_observer>
                        <class>[MyCustomModule_Model_Class_Groupname]/observer</class>
                        <method>beforeLoadLayout</method>
                    </my_current_page_is_observer>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_layout_load_before>
     </events>
   </frontend>
```

**Now on this of this handler,you can add a new block to layout  and a new phtml.**

Suppose, you want to change the layout at `Custom attribute set  page` then you can try this.

```
<PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_SET_Custom>
<reference name="root">
    <remove name="header" />
    <remove name="breadcrumbs" />
    <remove name="footer" />
</reference
</PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_SET_Custom>
```